# Hibernate: How to update parent_id field without retrieving parent from db?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, entitymanager

In a Spring Boot app, I have the following entities that have one-to-many relationship (Category is the parent of Recipe):

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Category category;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Recipe> recipes = new HashSet<>();

    public void addRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        recipes.add(recipe);
        recipe.setCategory(this);
    }

    public void removeRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
        recipes.remove(recipe);
        recipe.setCategory(null);
    }
}
```

When I create a Recipe, I send `categoryId` that is selected from Dropdown list and create Recipe by retrieving and adding category to the recipe as shown below:

```
@Transactional
public void update(RecipeRequest request) {
    final Category category = categoryRepository.findById(request.getCategoryId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException(NOT_FOUND_CATEGORY));

    /* instead of retrieving category, I want to set the categoryId field of Recipe, 
       but there is not such kind of setter */
    recipe.setCategoryId(request.getCategoryId());
    
    recipe.setTitle(capitalizeFully(request.getTitle()));
    recipe.setCategory(category);
    
    recipeRepository.save(recipe);
}
```

Instead of retrieving category, I want to set the categoryId field of Recipe, but there is not such kind of setter:

```
recipe.setCategoryId(request.getCategoryId());
```

So, what is the most proper way for just setting the categoryId of the recipe and then saving it without requiring the category from db? Do I need a setter for categoryId field to the Recipe (I thought it, but does not seem elegant way)?

Comment: Does anybody else have ever used Hibernate and update parent_id field?

Comment: you should have a categoryId field (and the corresponding public setter) in your Recipe class (it looks that your db table Recipe already has a category_id column,  referenced by the JoinColumn annotation)

Comment: @dsp_user I also think of it, but is there a more elegant way? Because it is not meaningful to add an extra field just for setting. Any idea?

Comment: I think it makes sense to add it because you have to set that column in your database when you're adding a new Recipe. Otherwise, you have to set category field and you certainly don't need the category field set when just inserting/adding new Recipes.

Comment: I am wondering what Hibernate users would do for this kind of scenarios. Do they retrieve the related parent record from db or do they add a new column for parentId ? Any idea?

Comment: Hibernate users? I'm sure you'll get all kinds of views from them as well.

Comment: But imagine a scenario where you have to add thousands of Recipes at once. What would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add a categoryId field along with the corresponding getter and settter methods to the Recipe class.

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String title;

 @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Category category;

@Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
private Integer categoryId;

// getters/setters

 }
```

Having a categoryId field means that when we don't have to create an instance of Category when adding new Recipes. Sure, Recipe.category will be null but that's ok if we're just adding new Recipes. This approach could also prove beneficial if we later decide that we need to add many Recipes simultaneously.

Comment: Good, it is working. But I needed to update as `@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)`

Comment: On the other hand, is it the only way I think if I don't want to set category_id field of recipe before saving or updating it. Right?

Comment: @Jack, it's not the only way, you can always resort to using native queries via either the Query annotation or JdbcTemplate. In fact, for more complex queries (regardless of if they're inserts, updates or selects) using native queries is often preferred because this way you'll generate more efficient/optimized queries. But , in the end, category_id will still need to be set.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository implements `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` you may take advantage of using `JpaRepository#getReferenceById` method, in that case Hibernate instead of querying DB for data will return proxy object. However, such implementation may cause issues in some cases, for example:

```java
// this call typically returns entity
// or null if entity wasn't found
repository.findById(id);
```

but:

```java
// this call returns proxy object
repository.getReferenceById(id);

// now instead of returning entity
// repository either returns initialized proxy 
// object or throws EntityNotFoundException
// if entity wasn't found
repository.findById(id);
```

Comment: Do you mean that first I call ``repository.getCategoryById(id);` and then `recipe.setCategoryId(request.getCategoryId());` ? Is there any other way to solve this problem in Hibernate?

Comment: `recipe.setCategory(categoryRepository.getReferenceById(request.getCategoryId()))`

Comment: As a result, I think we have to retrieve category from database in order to set its id in Recipe. There is not a more elegant way?  Is that true?

Comment: It seems good, but when I compare 2 approaches, it seems that using `findById` with .orElseThrow() seems the best way as it also throws exception for null cases. Any idea?